# Dataset legend color is not updating after changing background color of dataset and update (chartJs framework)

Tags: chart.js

I am kind of new in **chartJS** framework, but this seems very odd to me.
I have horizontal bar chart and 2 basic datasets in it. The thing is, that I am trying
to make a button, that will change background color of dataset (in my case -> for dataset 1, but it doesn't really matter, it's just testing scenario). When I click on my button, it will change background color of bars in graph, but it will not change background color of my dataset legend.

**Example:**
Dataset 1 has red background color. I click on my button and it will change background color of bars in graph on green(or some other color, it is not important). Legend of dataset 1 will stay red tho.

[Here is my code](https://github.com/bzagrapan/chartJsExample/blob/master/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### update()

> It's pretty common to want to update charts after they've been
> created. When the chart data or options are changed, Chart.js will
> animate to the new data values and options.
> https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html?h=update

**Official Scriptable example (change colors & data by click):**
https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scriptable/bar.html

or her (under the `scriptable title`): https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/

`myHorizontalBar` is your chart object so remove `window.` (Syntax error - check console errors).

```
window.myHorizontalBar.update(); /* wrong syntax remove "window." */
```

### "hello world" example

```js
/* data */
var data = {
  labels: ["Africa", "Asia", "Europe", "America"],
  datasets: [{
    /* data */
    label: "Data label",
    backgroundColor: ["red", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f", '#1d49b8'],
    data: [5.0,6.7,7.5, 8.6, 3.3, 4.4, 4.5]
  }]
};

var options = {
  responsive: true,
  title: {
    text: 'Hello',
    display: true
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      stacked: false,
      ticks: {

      },
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      stacked: true,
      ticks: {

      }
    }]
  }
};

var myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: options
});

document.getElementById('submitChange').addEventListener('click', function() {
  myChart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[0] = "green";
  myChart.update();
});
```

```html
<button id="submitChange">Change Africa color to Green</button>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Chart that I posted on GitHub was just copy of official example from chart.js github (https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/samples/charts/bar/horizontal.html). Your example is working tho, thanks :) Next time, I will try to post just code snippets.